# Real-time update absolute positioned div when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset, absolute

Let me explain the situation:

There is a **relative** positioned `sidebar`. After scrolling past the top of the `main-content` this sidebar changes to **absolute** and is then real-time updated to the top position in the window (scrollTop of the window).

The problem is that it is really slow and choppy (in Firefox) because it is updating the whole time. How can I update the position 'real-time' without so much load?

Currently it looks like this:

```
var headerOffset = $('#main-content').offset().top;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if( ($(document).scrollTop() + 15) > $('#main-content').offset().top ){
    $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
    $('#sidebar').css('top', ( $(document).scrollTop() - headerOffset) + 15 );
  } else {
    $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post html/css please ?

Comment: Tip: change if( ($(document).scrollTop() + 15) > $('#main-content').offset().top ) to if( ($(document).scrollTop() + 15) > headerOffset ). This way your code doesn't have to recalculate the offset of your main-content element everytime u scroll. For more help please post your html/css or a jsfiddle like Cyril asked.

Comment: Ah yes, the recalculating is not needed when scrolling. Thank you! Here is a fiddle with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/u3GpS/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to do all the Javascript hassle because you have unpredictable headers and don't know the exact position of main content it wold be enough to set the ccs to fixed and just calculate the position on start.

```
var headerOffset = $('#main-content').offset().top;
$('#sidebar').css('top', headerOffset);
```

like here:http://jsfiddle.net/4amdr/

Thats the only way I can imagine why you don't want to use a fixed top and leave js out.

Comment: I can't use fixed because the sidebar is in a flexible container.

Here is a fiddle to explain the problem better: http://jsfiddle.net/4amdr/1/

The container has a width and is centered. The sidebar needs to stay on the right side of the container.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, had too sleep:-) Okay, I wrapped the sidebar in a holder div with 25% percent width and just adjust the width to that of the holder on a resize event, which should not happen too often. Look if this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/WsMDj/

Comment: Note that the fist two lines of script are not needed any more: http://jsfiddle.net/WsMDj/3/

Comment: Wow! Really clean and much better than the other answers/solutions. Works perfect :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you should use affix from twitter bootstrap : [Bootstrap's affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix)

Comment: I'm aware of Bootstrap affix, but I'm trying to solve it without using it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

=> http://jsfiddle.net/8XVXj/1/ or a full exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/8XVXj/2/

```
var headerOffset = $('#main-content').offset().top;
$(document).on('scroll', function(){
 if( ($(document).scrollTop() + 15) > $('#main-content').offset().top ){
   if($('#sidebar').hasClass('fixed') === false) {
     $('#sidebar').addClass('fixed');
     $('#sidebar').css('top', ($(document).scrollTop() - headerOffset) + 15 );
   }
 } else {
   $('#sidebar').removeClass('fixed');
 }
});
```

I add only once the position fixed.

Comment: The delay is gone now, but I still have a feeling this could be done better. There are 2 if statements just to see if it should watch the scroll and that feels it bit unnecessary.. Thank you for your solution and I will check if it works properly.

Comment: I just fix your code but if I have to code this I will do it differently, if event and without jquery. If my answer works, thanks to tag my post as solution.

Comment: The delay is gone now, but I still have a feeling this could be done better. The code feels a bit bloated.. But thank you for your solution and I will check if it works properly.